# Simple DataSource (Not XA) in persistence.xml

Tags: spring, jpa, jta

If I am using "transaction-type" JTA in "persistence.xml" ,
then is it mandatory to use XA type data sources in "" element ?
 or we can also using simple data source also .

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If you want to use JTA and have multiple participants (i.e. datasources, jms connections etc) then you really must have an XA capable datasource. When you don't have this you have problems starting a distributed transaction.

If this is the only participant ever then you might even wonder why do you want JTA transactions and stick with resource local transactions.

Comment: thanks deinum !!! so if only one datasource is participant in JTA transactions , then it can be either XA or simple . is it ?

Comment: In theory but that might differ between JTA implementations. I know WebSphere allows for a single non-xa resource to participate in a distributed transaction, not sure about other implementations.

Comment: That is correct. Now related to the part "why not stick with resource local transactions" the answer is pretty simple: because in @Transactional methods only JTA resources are automatically managed by the container (tested only in EJBs in JBoss).

Comment: Not when using Spring, spring takes then the role of container and will manage your resources.